# French babel package ruins my page setup!

Tags: babel, babel-french

First of all: I use Overleaf as my LaTeX compiler.

Being french, I wanted to use

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,french]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
```

in my declarations, instead of

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
```

However, in addition of the expected change in, e.g., the date (april became avril), some lines are now entangled! See the screenshots.

Any idea why? Amazingly enough, I tried with German babel, and no problem...

[image: My resume, with only the small change describes...]

Here is my full document (with lorem ipsum of course) :

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}%,french] OR \documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,french]{article}
%\usepackage{babel}
\newlength{\outerbordwidth}
\pagestyle{empty}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed,tabularx,array}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{color,hyperref}
\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   


%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Edit these values as you see fit

\setlength{\outerbordwidth}{3pt}  % Width of border outside of title bars
\definecolor{shadecolor}{gray}{0.75}  % Outer background color of title bars (0 = black, 1 = white)
\definecolor{shadecolorB}{gray}{0.93}  % Inner background color of title bars


%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Margin setup

\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.25in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{11in}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{8.5in}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.5in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{7in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.3in}
\setlength{\topskip}{0in}
\setlength{\voffset}{0.1in}


%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands
%\newcommand{\Cpp}{C\raisebox{0.5ex}{\tiny\textbf{++ }}}
\newcommand{\Cpp}{C\texttt{++\thinspace}}
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{\vspace{8pt}
  \parbox{\textwidth}{\setlength{\FrameSep}{\outerbordwidth}
    \begin{shaded}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\framebox[\textwidth][l]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}\fcolorbox{shadecolorB}{shadecolorB}{\textbf{\sffamily{\mbox{~}\makebox[6.762in][l]{\large #1} \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}}}
    \end{shaded}
  }\vspace{-5pt}
}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{
\begin{tabularx}{6.5in}{X<{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}@{}r}
  \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
  \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
\end{tabularx}\vspace{-6pt}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{7in}{Xr}

\textbf{\Large Lorem Ipsum} & \textbf{\today}
\\
Dolorem & \href{mailto:me@somewhere.fr}{\nolinkurl{mailto:me@somewhere.fr}} \\
42 My place & 01 23 45 67 89 \\
\end{tabularx}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\resheading{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{itemize}

\item \ressubheading{consectetur adipiscing elit. }{Sed non risus tortor}{dignissim sit amet}{}

\begin{itemize}
    \resitem{ Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat.}
    \resitem{Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue.}
    \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}[![Difference between the two versions][1]][1]
```

Comment: It is normal the french option of babel writes  dates in the French language.

Comment: french changes not only names but also layout related things like the list layout. You will have to adapt your definitions and e.g. remove the \vspace{-6pt}.

Comment: @Bernard : obviously this is the wanted effect. The entangled lines effect, however...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : thanks, this seems to do the trick! (kindly add it as the answer so I can close the question)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : where can I find a list of the modifications brought by the french babel?

Comment: The spacings inists are tighter than the standard ones. You have a set of optionds described in  § 1.2, pp. 5–10 of the documentation.

Comment: There is a frenchb.pdf which you get with `texdoc babel-french`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

french changes not only names but also layout related things like the list layout.

You will have to adapt your definitions and e.g. remove the `\vspace{-6pt}` in the definition of `\ressubheading`.

Comment: thanks. best thing I could come up with: use english as the default language, and for example the date becomes: \selectlanguage{french}{\today}

Answer (score 4):

`babel-french` provides many options to customize the layout, see the documentation, files `frenchb.pdf` (in English) or `frenchb-doc.pdf` (in French).

If you do not want `babel-french` to interfere at all with the layout, just add `\frenchsetup{StandardLayout}`.